# Why does this method compile?

Tags: java, android, syntax

Why does this method compile?

```
    private int test(){
      return R.string.test;
    }
```

`R.string.test` is defined this way in my android `strings.xml` file:

```
<resources>

     <string name="test">Test</string>  

</resources>
```

Everything I know about logic, the universe and life itself currently makes no sense. Please help a confused soul.

Comment: hard guess, you did not import R. or you have the wrong import

Comment: Clean your project then definitely it will not compile next time. This may be possible first time you have created the test string and it generates test id in R.java . When you clean the project it again generates the fresh id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your resources, android code generator reads the `resources` file and generate a java file `R.java` with all the `resources id` and thats why the code is compiled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`R.string.teste` get id of string as integer. So i didn't see any problems...

To get string you should write `context.getResources().getString(R.string.teste)`

Comment: yours is definitely a comment

Comment: Of course, it's early morning and i still didn't have my coffee. Can't believe how long it took me thinking about that one.

Comment: @user253296 hold the windows key then click the `test`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
private String test(){
    String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.test);
    return mess;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android, all the resources located in the `res` folder are compiled in a class called `R.java`, there, you have an identifier of the resource created. For example, inside of the `R.java` class there is a sub class called `string` for the Strings, `id` for the ids and so on. In your example you will have:

```
public final class R {

    // Other stuff   

    public static final class string {
        public static final int test=0x7f05001c;
        // More String resources
    }

    // Other stuff

}
```

So when you are doing `return R.string.test;` you are returning the id for that resource, in my example `0x7f05001c`

If what you want is retrieve the string itself, instead of its id, you need to do what @Suvitruf told you: `context.getResources().getString(R.string.test)`